# Kafka server throwing no disk available although space is available

Tags: apache-kafka

I am seeing below error in kafka server logs while running with RD Kafka Client. But when I see my disk space it has sufficient available space on disk.

```
[2018-10-08 14:41:44,458] ERROR Error while appending records to __consumer_offsets-20 in dir /var/opt/UMB/kafka/kafka-logs (kafka.server.LogDirFailureChannel)
java.io.IOException: No space left on device
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write(FileDispatcherImpl.java:60)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.write(FileChannelImpl.java:211)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.MemoryRecords.writeFullyTo(MemoryRecords.java:93)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.record.FileRecords.append(FileRecords.java:152)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.append(LogSegment.scala:136)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$append$2.apply(Log.scala:735)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$append$2.apply(Log.scala:640)
        at kafka.log.Log.maybeHandleIOException(Log.scala:1678)
        at kafka.log.Log.append(Log.scala:640)
```

Kafka Server version: kafka_2.11-1.1.0
RD Kakfa Client(librdkafka) version: 0.11.5

`df -k` showing around 60% disk space is free.

Comment: Diagnosis of storage issues is probably a better question for [unix.se]

Comment: @cricket_007 may be. is there any way to directly move this question to there?

Comment: I think it needs a moderator to do so. In any case, it would be useful if you could show how you're checking you're available disk space.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You might have open file handles that are not being closed and actually deleted. https://askubuntu.com/a/390301/699350

Answer (score 0):

Did you find the root cause? I am also getting same error while around 60+% of disk is available on the broker. When I increased the disk size by 100GB, it solved the problem.
What configuration of segment.ms you were using? In my case it was 100ms.